# Launching the camera from the mobile browser

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, camera, mobile-safari

I want to launch the camera from my mobile browser(Safari) in my iPhone. Is there a way to do

it. I guess in `iOS 6` I can do it , but I am not aware of how to achieve my task .

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open Camera from your mobile browser. For this you need to use Some Already available Javascript APIs. Like we have in PhoneGAP framework. You can see the example at this [Link.](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html)

Comment: Are you writing a native application?? Can you please elaborate your question??

Comment: I am not writing an app , I assumed that I have to do it code wise .I just want to launch the camera from my iphone browser

Comment: I need the steps to achieve  it.

Comment: Which type of code you are going to write? is it for Safari based html code or native app development??

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Is it possible to launch the camera from the browser using objective C code(Native app)? or using html 5 is the only option ?

Comment: If you want to open camera using your browser, HTML5 is only option. Either if you want to do it in your application, you can write native code to fulfill this need.

Comment: Is there a way to include HTML5 code along with my objective C code using XCode

Comment: Why would you need Objective C in your browser? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Jimpic : As I am beginner in ios this is really confusing me . How to include this API ?

Comment: See the link in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS6, you can try the following if what you are trying to accomplish is setting up a web page which will open the camera from safari.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
<input type="file" accept="video/*" capture="camera">
```

It will act like a regular file upload, but instead, it will open the iPhone camera and upload a picture or a video.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the idea; it was successful on an android, too. Version 4.4.2. LG G2